# Generate all contiguous sequences from an array

Tags: java, arrays, logic

There's an array say [1,2,4,5,1]. I need to print all the contiguous sub-arrays from this.

Input: `[1,2,4,5,1]`

Output:

```
 1
 1,2
 1,2,4
 1,2,4,5
 1,2,4,5,1
 2
 2,4
 2,4,5
 2,4,5,1
 4
 4,5
 4,5,1
 5
 5,1
 1
```

I tried but couldn't get the complete series.

```
//items is the main array
for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    int num = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < items.length - i; j++) {
        for(int k = i; k < j; k++) {
            System.out.print(items[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: so ... what is your actual question? what is it you're stuck with?

Comment: @Stultuske i'm not getting the exact series! I'm looking for a proper logic to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You only have to make 2 changes. The outer loop iterates as much times as the array has elements, this is correct. The first inner loop should use the index of the outer loop as start index (`int j = i`), otherwise you always start with the first element. And then change the inner loop break conditon to `k <= j`, otherwise `i` does not print the last element.

```
// i is the start index
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    // j is the number of elements which should be printed
    for (int j = i; j < items.length; j++)
    {
        // print the array from i to j
        for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(items[k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do in less than 3 loops?

Comment: @AliAkram This algorithm has a runtime complexity of  O(n²) so you need at least two loops. My code uses only two loops for generating the sequences. The third loop is only for printing. You can replace the inner loop with `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOfRange(items, i, j + 1)));`

Comment: @AliAkram yes possible to use less than 3 loops. Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70754152/11421611

Answer (score 2):

```
// Javascript.
// Generate Array and print it.
function subArray(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 1) return 0;
    if (arr.length < 2) return arr[0];

    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const temp = [];
        for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            temp.push(arr[j]);
            result.push([...temp]);
            console.log(temp.join(','));
        }
    }
    return result
}

// Calculate only Sum of the subarrays.
function subArrSum(arr) {
  if (arr.length < 1) return 0;
  if (arr.length < 2) return arr[0];

  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += (arr.length - i) * (i + 1) * arr[i];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Using loop twice. To get just sum, I suggested using pattern of the subarrays.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working! Try this algorithm.

```
for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++) {

        for(int j=i;j<items.length;j++) {

            for(int k=i;k<=j;k++) {

                System.out.print(items[k]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
int items[]={1,2,4,5,1};
for(int i=0;i<=items.length;i++)//items is the main array 
{
    int num=0;
    for(int j=0;j<items.length;j++)
    {
        for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(items[k]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is correct, but with much extra spaces between the lines :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
import java.io.*;
class stack
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        int items[]={1,2,4,5,1};

        for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++)//items is the main array 
        {
            for(int j=i;j<items.length;j++)
            {
                for(int k=i;k<=j;k++)
                {
                    System.out.print(items[k]);
                    if (k==j)
                        continue;
                    else
                        System.out.print(",");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help

```
for(int i=0;i<=items.length-1;i++)
{
    for(int l=i;l<=items.length;l++)
    {
    int b[]=Arrays.copyOfRange(a, i,l);

        for(int k=0;k<=b.length-1;k++)
        {
            System.out.print(b[k]);
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one better approach that takes less time:

Input:

```
int items[] = {1,2,3,4};
```

Code:

```
int j = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){ 

   sb.setLength(0);
   j = 0;
   sb.append(items[i]+ " ");
   System.out.print(sb.toString()+ " ");
   System.out.println();

   j=i+1;
   
   while(j< items.length){

       sb.append(arr.get(j) + " ");
       System.out.print(sb.toString() +" ");
       System.out.println();

       j = j+1;
   }
   System.out.println();
   }
```

Output:

```
  1
  1 2
  1 2 3
  1 2 3 4

  2 
  2 3
  2 3 4
  
  3
  3 4

  4
```

Answer (score 0):

def printSubsequences(l, r, arr:list, n):

```
if(l == n):
    return
while(l<=r):
    print(arr[l:r+1])
    r-=1
printSubsequences(l+1, n-1, arr, n)
```

if `__name__` == `"__main__"`:
arr = list(map(int, input("Enter : ").strip().split()))
printSubsequences(0, len(arr)-1, arr, len(arr))

Answer (score 0):

```
static void printContiguousSequence(int[] arr, int fromIndex, int toIndex)   {
    if (toIndex > arr.length)
        return;

    for (int i = fromIndex; i < toIndex; i++) {
        System.out.print(arr[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();

    if (toIndex == arr.length) {
        fromIndex++;
        toIndex = fromIndex;
    }
    printContiguousSequence(arr, fromIndex, toIndex + 1);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 2, 4, 5, 1 };
    printContiguousSequence(arr, 0, 1);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be with your second loop:

```
for(int j=0;j<items.length-i;j++)
```

You're always running on the first i places. What you want to do is run from i until the end of the array, as such:

```
for(int j=i;j<items.length;j++)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<items.length; i++)
{
   for(int j=i; j<items.length; j++)
   {
      System.out.print(items[j]);
   }
   System.out.println();
}
```

I haven't tested yet, but it should work.

Comment: No it does not work. It prints the whole array, then only the last four elements, then the last three elements and so on...